# какой самый быстрый способ отрисовки графики?

Tags: java, android, canvas, graphics

Вот есть кнопка , я нажимаю на неё и двигаю по экрану , но когда я быстро двигаю палец по экрану эта кнопка заметно отстает от пальца. Делаю вывод, что кнопка не успевает быстро отрисовываться или же частота обновления экрана не достаточная . Как можно решить подобную проблему? какими средствами лучше рисовать , используя Canvas ,Surface view или что то другое ? Вопрос , естественно , касательно Java.

```
public class MainActivity1 extends Activity  {

public static float touchX = 50,touchY= 50;
private float korX = touchX, korY = touchY, initX=0, initY=0;
static int width;
static int heigth;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // GraphicsView myview = new GraphicsView(this); 
    setContentView(new GraphicsView(this)); 
    display();
}

public void display(){
     width = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
     heigth = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
    return;
}

public class GraphicsView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback  {

    private DrawThread drawThread;

    public GraphicsView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        getHolder().addCallback(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder){
        drawThread = new DrawThread(getHolder(),getResources());
        drawThread.setRunning(true);
        drawThread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        boolean retry = true;
        drawThread.setRunning(false);
        while (retry) {
            try {
                drawThread.join();
                retry = false;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            }
        }
    }
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                korX = touchX;
                korY = touchY;
                initX = event.getRawX();
                initY = event.getRawY();
                return true;
           case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                   touchX = (korX + (event.getRawX() - initX));
                   touchY = (korY + (event.getRawY() - initY));
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Поток в котором идет отрисовка

```
 public class DrawThread extends Thread {

private boolean running = false;
private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
private Matrix matrix;
private long prevTime;

public Bitmap bitmap;

public DrawThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder,Resources resources){
    this.surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
      bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.face_box);
}

public  void  setRunning(boolean running){
    this.running = running;                 
}

@Override
public  void  run(){
    while (running){
        Canvas canvas = null;
        try {
            canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
            if (canvas == null)
                continue;
          synchronized (surfaceHolder) {
              MainActivity1.touchY, null);
              canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
                onDraw(canvas);

          }

        } finally {
            if (canvas != null){
                surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }
        }
    }
}


protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, MainActivity1.touchX, MainActivity1.touchY, null);
}
}
```

Comment: `SurfaceView` использует для отрисовки `Canvas`, сравнивать их не имеет смысла. Приложите код отрисовки кнопки, если это ваша кастомная кнопка, либо код, которым вы меняете положение кнопки в простарнстве, скорее всего там что то не так
P.S. Двигать элементы интерфейса - это очень нестандартный юзер-экспириенс. Задумайтесь, возможно вы пытаетесь создать функционал только ради функционала, т.к. пользователи вряд ли оценят

Comment: @P.Ilyin Позвольте не согласиться. Как по мне это стандартный Drag'N'Drop, которому уже порядка 30 лет. Помимо этого, любой Android пользователь рано или поздно сталкивается с настройкой виджетов на экране, которая и заключается в перетаскивании элементов для удобства.

Comment: Скорее дело в сопоставлении координат касания и координат расположения кнопки, как сказано выше. Поверьте коррекцию положения кнопки в зависимости от её длины/ширины. Не раз с таким поведением сталкивался.

Comment: Перетаскивание элементов homeScreen'a это одно, совсем другое - менять положение элементов UI в приложении. Facebook, к примеру, был скачан 1 млрд раз и там нет ничего подобного. Единственное, что приходит на ум - перетаскивание аудиозаписей в ВК, но там это вполне оправдано (юзер хочет разный прядок воспроизведения).
В итоге, отложим этот спор и вы все-таки приложите часть кода

Comment: Да и вправду я должен был рассказать о том, что я хочу реализовать. Проблема вот в чем. есть на экране шарик, я его хочу двигать пальцем по экрану, но когда я начинаю ускоренно двигать пальцем этот шарик отстает. А цель сделать игру, где этот шарик убегает от других двигающихся по экрану шариков (Игра типо HARD или iгений, вы должно быть знакомы с ней) В общем вопросы про то нужен ли такой функционал отпадают. onTouchEvent получает координаты, которые передаются в onDraw(Canvas canvas) для отрисовки. к вопросу приложу код, может  в нем проблема.

Comment: Но замечу , что ни в одном приложении не видел, чтобы перетаскиваемый объект не отставал от пальца, при быстром движении он всегда отстает (не отстает на компе при перетаскивании курсором в флэш например играх)  Так же скажу , что в examples ,которые прилагаются к EndАngine двигаемый объект так же отстает. Я думаю узкое место тут передача координат на отрисовку, это происходит не достаточно быстро.

Comment: я вот знаю , что можно еще gesturedetector использовать, только я не знаю, его принципиального отличия от метода Ontouch. Но есть такое подозрение , что нельзя быстрее передавать координаты на отрисовку, так как подобных приложений на андроид я не встречал) везде где реализовано "перетаскивание", перетаскиваемый объект отстает от пальца,если тащить быстро. В игре это создает небольшой дискомфорт. В приложениях не заметно.и еще вопрос  Drag'N'Drop это всего лишь общее название всего, что связано с перетаскиванием или он подразумевает, какие то особенные методы?